# Why does `[a-zA-Z]*` not match a word with leading whitespace?

Tags: regex, vim

Given a string like so:

```
    aWordToRemove;
```

Turn it into this:

```
    TEST;
```

If I run the command `:s/[a-zA-Z]*/TEST/` then it doesn't match anything.

However if I run `:s/[a-zA-Z]\w*/TEST/` then it will replace `aWordToRemove` with `TEST` and leave both the leading white spaces and trailing semi-colon intact.

Why doesn't the first regex find the word if it has leading whitespace?

Why does putting `\w` just before the `*` work?

**EDIT:**

Vim seems to be finicky. Here are some of the working and not working regex.

*Working Regexes*

`s/[a-zA-Z]\w*/TEST/`

`s/[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*/TEST/`

`s/[a-zA-Z]\+/TEST/`

*Not Working Regexes*

`s/[a-zA-Z]*/TEST/`

`s/[a-zA-Z]+/TEST/`

Comment: Because you need a global modifier. Or better a `+`  instead of `*`. Else, the pattern matches at the start.

Comment: The pattern you need is `s/[a-zA-Z]\+/TEST/`

Comment: Do you know why the backslash is necessary?

Comment: It's just part of the [spec](http://vimregex.com/). The creators apparently thought `+` should be the character, and `\+` should be the quantifier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because it finds the empty string between the line start and the first space, and replaces it with the empty string, and then stops.

You can try `:s/[a-zA-Z]*//g` instead, which will keep trying after the first replace.

The Kleene closure (`*`) is capable of matching nothing. A similar expression, like yours, that will work is `:s/[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*//`, which guarantees that at least one letter is matched, preventing it from stopping when it matches its first empty string. In fact, this is so common that the operator `a+` is shorthand for `aa*` in most regular expression dialects.

That's the reason why `:s/[a-zA-Z]\w*//` works, because it has to match at least one letter before consuming more.

Comment: Or change the `*` to a `+`

Comment: `:s/[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*//` == `:s/[a-zA-Z]+//`

Comment: In vim, you'll need to put a backslash before the `+`. Vim is fun that way.

Comment: @ncphillips: Different regular expression dialects are different. Regular expressions only define four operations: precedence (typically `(` and `)`), Kleene closure (typically `*`), union (typically `|`) and concatenation (typically just characters). All other operations are extensions of these and therefore different software does it differently.

Comment: I tried a command `:s/[^a-z]*/#/g`  with a file containing the word `word` as a result it gave me `#w#o#r#d#` .

Comment: @Meninx: Is that what you expected? Do you have a question about that behaviour? The reason that happens is because `a*` can match the string of zero length, for any value of `a` (in your case, `a=[^a-z]`). There is a zero-length string between every character in the string `word`, as well as before and after the string itself.

Comment: I wasn't expecting that I thought that it has only replaced the `^` character (the beginning of the line) but it looks like as you said it can substitute the zero length string which is nothing. Thanks @Welbog !

Comment: @Meninx: The carat (`^`) usually has a different meaning inside of a character class (between `[` and `]`) compared to outside. Outside, it means the beginning of the line/string. Inside, it means "not". `[^abc]` means "any character but `a`, `b` and `c`.

Comment: I am totally aware of that but usually we refer to the beginning of the line by the character `^` that's why ! :)

Answer (score 3):

To learn vimregex, `magic`, `very magic` and `no magic` should be learned first. `:h magic` to see details.

Vim has `magic` set as default. `magic` is BRE **-like**, which means, you have to escape some chars to give them special meaning, otherwise, they are just literal chars. like `( ) | + ...` If we talk about this point, it is same as BRE.

If you want to make the regex ERE or PCRE **-like**, you can put a `\v` before your pattern, thus: `:s/\v[...]+/whatever/g` will work. In this `very magic` mode, you have to escape those chars with special meaning to have there literal value.

I suggest you reading the vim `magic` doc, there is a table, to compare different magic modes. And you can do some tests.